# What does $dateFormat variable actually do in Laravel Model?

Tags: laravel, date, datetime

I can't see any difference if I set this variable or not.

I need some basic example

if this variable is set:

```
protected $dateFormat = "d.m.Y H:i";
```

What difference does it make???

P.S. I have already read about in Docu but it's not clear where is this date format actually used??

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

#### Update

---

- Using jQuery datetimepicker localized so the date that gets saved is in this format: "25.09.2017 08:04"
- changed the column data type in migration from timestamp to dateTime.
- changed timezone in config/app.php to: `'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',`
- set the variable to:

  ```
    protected $dateFormat = "d.m.Y H:i";
  ```

And I get an error on form submit:

[image]

and if I the variable is NOT set

I get this error:

[image]

Comment: One more time to be clear, it is not the problem to save the date I have made a setter I just want to know where in practice is this variable used where does it take effect?

Comment: Is the published_at attribute part of your $dates array? Can you show your entire model?

Comment: Yes it is...I will post in a few hours when I get home

Comment: I've updated my answer; the first paragraph was clearly wrong. I did another read of the source code, and $dateFormat is used both for incoming post data and when serialising values to the database. This means that your posts needs to use the database format (or you need a setter that changes the parsing). In a slightly sarcastic voice; can you reconfigure your database server to match your UI?

Comment: The reason I posted this question was this: I thought that this $dateFormat variable was changing the date from post to that format... So it's obvious that it doesn't do that. And you are saying that it is used for both incoming post data and when serialising values to the database... But I can't see the difference... In any case either I set the variable or not i get an error. What I don't understand is why are they different...from my point of view I thought that this variable changes the posted date from "25.09.2017 11:55" to this "2017-09-25 11:55" on form post. But it doesn't do that.

Comment: We can send messages here to each other but if You could make a simple example it would clear a lot of things out.

Comment: and I am not using this `<input type="datetime-local">` my input type for date is `type="text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your `$dateFormat` is used to both parse incoming post data, and format data sent to your database. This means that, without any other code (read: setter that overrides this), your UI must use the same datetime format as your database.

---

The `$dateFormat` is used by `HasAttributes::asDateTime` to [parse incoming strings into Carbon objects](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bfbe20d32ee9f98c89df852847827407a5127be4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L711-L716). This method is used in many places to handle automatic casting of the attributes into proper data types. This includes both the `$casts` array and the `$dates` array.

One common invocation is via `Model::fill(...)` > `HasAttributes::setAttribute(...)` > `HasAttributes::fromDateTime(...)`. Note that `Model::__set(...)` also calls into `HasAttributes::setAttribute(...)`. This means that the `$dateFormat` is used to parse incoming string values from [presumed] form posts when you use mass-assignment/fillable, or when you set attributes directly using `$model->myField = ...;`. You're expected to set the format to what the browsers are posting so the values can be properly parsed into Carbon objects.

The Carbon objects are then serialised back into strings in `HasAttributes::fromDateTime(...)` which means that Laravel handles your datetime values as strings, which surprised me when researching this. This means that your $attributes array contains string representation of your datetime values, and these string values are sent to the database. 
This means that `$dateFormat` needs to produce a string value supported by your database.

Keep in mind that this is the format of the datetime value when submitted, not shown. The datetime-local html5 datatype, for example, will use the local locale when formatting the datetime, but will always post the value in a specified format.

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's operating system, whereas the date value is always formatted yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: I am using a datetime picker in front end that has a format like this "d.m.Y H:i" => "24.09.2017 22:59" and if I don't convert the date for mysql it will throw an error on store or update. So can this variable help me somehow or not?

Comment: I thought that if I set the $dateFormat variable to this: "d.m.Y H:i" then I can store the date from datepicker in that format... but it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score -2):

That is the format how it is saved in the database.

Comment: No it is not, I have set it like this protected $dateFormat = "Y-m-d H:i"; and I get an error: Unexpected data found. Trailing data

Comment: And If I set it like this protected $dateFormat = "d.m.Y H:i"; I get this error: Invalid datetime format

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use this instead of a mutator? Something like:                                                    `public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
}`

Comment: I have solved that problem I use a setter now....And just want to know what is this variable for?

Comment: why was my answer downvoted? it's still right, even though short

Comment: My dateFormat is "d.m.Y H:i" and whatever change I made with that variable I always got an error. So it doesn't change the format for saving the date.